# Rule of thumb for tables versus "blobs" to display data?

Tags: website-design, web-app

What's a rule of thumb for when use rows and columns (i.e. tables) versus single or multi-line "blobs" to display data? I swear I'm right on the fence for several screens of a complex administration interface for a database.

My own primary differentiator tends to be sorting/filtering. If you are going to do that by more than few variables, it's probably a table. I should also mention I think it is my duty to explore all other options before settling on a table because they tend to be the default go-to in engineering-heavy products.

Thanks! This is my first post.

Answer (score 3):

The following are guidelines that I typically use when making this decision.

#### Tables are good when comparing data points across records/sorting/filtering.

Use a table display when:

- it is important to be able to visually compare values from several different records (e.g. which address records are from Spain, order records by users' last name)
- you'd like your users to think of this data as instances of the same thing (e.g. inventory management, employee time tracking)

#### Cards (or "blobs") are good when records don't need to be compared to each other.

Use a card display when:

- users have no need to sort/compare data between records (e.g. Twitter feed, book reviews)
- you'd like your users to think of these things as distinct objects (e.g. presenting a variety of sports products and details to a user, showing a user a number of different document templates to choose from)

Comment: Good summation, @maxathousand. My various screens are a little of each case above, so it remains a tough decision. But it's very helpful to hear someone else's rule of thumb.